# No webapp folder in output jar

Tags: web-applications, jar, spring-boot, vaadin

I'm building a simple web application using Vaadin and Spring Boot. When I build it using `mvn package` and run via `java -jar <path_to_jar>` it seems to work.

But one thing puzzles me. When I'm inside the project folder and run `java -jar target/app.jar` it seems to be working properly. But if I go outside and run it as `java -jar <full_path_to_jar>` it works, but the theme is gone. I checked the output of Chrome Inspector and it returns `404` for `/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css?v=7.5.5`

How do I package the theme into the jar?

Answer (score 4):

Judging by your question's title, it sounds like you've used `src/main/webapp`. As [explained in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content), you shouldn't do that when building a jar:

> Do not use the `src/main/webapp` directory if your application will be packaged as a jar. Although this directory is a common standard, it will only work with war packaging and it will be silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.

Instead, you should put your static content beneath `src/main/resources/static`.